# How can I configure icinga/nagios to alert via sms?

Tags: nagios, alerts, icinga

I know the sms gateway for my cell phone provider so I can just send an email to it.

I am looking for examples of entries in contacts.cfg and commands.cfg that are mobile specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `contacts_nagios2.cfg`:

```
define contactgroup{
        contactgroup_name       admins
        alias                   Nagios Administrators
        members                 user
}
define contact{
        contact_name                    name
        alias                           name
        service_notification_period     24x7
        host_notification_period        24x7
        service_notification_options    w,u,c,r
        host_notification_options       d,r
        service_notification_commands   notify-by-sms
        host_notification_commands      host-notify-by-sms
        email                           mail
        pager                          MOBILENUMBER
}
```

And in `commands.cfg`

```
define command{
       command_name notify-by-sms
       command_line script-to-sms-service
}
define command{
       command_name host-notify-by-sms
       command_line script-to-sms-service
}
```

Comment: How would I be able to limit the texts to 160 characters? Is there any standard way of doing that?

Comment: You can either impose that limit through your script (trim) or check that your plug-ins never produce more than 160 characters.

Answer (score 3):

Using a 3rd-party SMS service, or (even better) using a GSM device as Craig suggests, is going to be much more reliable/robust.

If you're dead set on using the provider's email->SMS gateway, you can use slimmed-down contact commands like this:

```
define command {
    command_name    notify-host-by-sms
    command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n$HOSTNAME$ is $HOSTSTATE$\n$HOSTOUTPUT$\n" | /usr/bin/mail -s "[Nagios] ($HOSTNAME$ $HOSTSTATE$)" $CONTACTEMAIL$
```

}

```
define command {
    command_name    notify-service-by-sms
    command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n$SERVICEDESC$ ($HOSTNAME$) is $SERVICESTATE$\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$" | /usr/bin/mail -s "[Nagios] ($HOSTNAME$/$SERVICEDESC$)" $CONTACTEMAIL$
```

If any of these end up being too long, you can remove or substitute different macros in several places, as necessary. See [the macro list](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/macrolist.html) for info on what's available in a notification command.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer will do what you need.

You can send SMS messages through an SMS service, send them via the cell providers email to SMS addresses, or use a local SMS server. We did the latter. This link will give you details on how to do it:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/using-sms-server-provide-robust-alerting-service-nagios

This has been running for 1.5 yrs. Very reliable, and not dependent on email servers, or third party services.

Answer (score -2):

If you want something that can be used out-of-the-box, you can take a look at [SMSEagle](http://www.smseagle.eu)

That's a hardware sms gateway. Their advantage is that the device stands close to your infrastructure, so when your Internet connection fails you can still send your SMS alerts.

They have ready [plugin for Nagios](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Notifications/SMS/SMS-Notifications-and-Alerting-via-SMSEagle/details) - integration takes about 5min.

Comment: All of your answers, so far, link this same product. I should hope you're not here only to promote it. Please see the section labeled [How not to be a spammer](http://serverfault.com/help/promotion) from the site help.